# How to pass data in startActivityForResult() and get it back inside onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's my `startActivityForResult()`:

```
val initialPosition = frame.tag as Int
val currentPosition = constraint.indexOfChild(frame)
Log.d(TAG, "initial position: $initialPosition") // prints initial position: 2
Log.d(TAG, "current position: $currentPosition") // prints current position: 2
val galleryIntent = Intent().apply {
  type = "image/*"
  action = Intent.ACTION_PICK
  putExtra("initialPosition", initialPosition)
  putExtra("currentPosition", currentPosition)
  setResult(5)
}
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Pick image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

However, I'm unable to retrieve the data here:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG, "ResultCode: $resultCode SUCCESS") // prints -1 SUCCESS
    }
    when (requestCode){
        PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "${data?.getIntExtra("initialPosition", 0)}") // prints 0
            Log.d(TAG, "${data?.extras?.getInt("initialPosition")}") // prints 0
            Log.d(TAG, "${data?.extras?.getInt("currentPosition")}") // prints 0
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You have to set the result in the started activity.

Comment: I just did `setResult(5)` to my `galleryIntent` however I'm getting a `-1` `resultCode` in my `onActivityResult()` - does this mean the function failed to retrieve the URI of the image? I've updated my code if you'd like to see @AhmadSattout

Comment: There are 2 setResult overloads. One has 1 Param and the other 2. The first param is the resultCode. While the other is the intent containing the data.

Comment: You can't. As per your code shows you are using system image picker which will return new intent with result. Your result will be ignored. I'm not sure why you need to add those parameter with image picker and get it back on activity result while you are in same class. You can use them directly by declaring those variable globally.

Answer (score 0):

`setResult()` will not set `galleryIntent`'s result code. The one that will set that result is the activity that you picked during `Intent.ACTION_PICK`.

Assuming you picked the system image picker. It will return `RESULT_OK`(which is -1) if you select an image, and return `RESULT_CANCELED`(which is 0) if you backpress.

Note that you cannot change what other activity returns for `resultCode` if you use an `Implicit Intent`, which is what you just did.